# Async utility for Node.js Call back function not executing

Tags: node.js, asynccallback

I am trying to use the async utility for the node.js. Below is my code. The console prints "In my func1" and "In my func2". I also expect it to print "call back func" but it won'nt

```
var myfunc1 = function(callback) {
var a = 1;
console.log ("In my func1");
};
var myfunc2 = function(callback) {
var b = 2;
console.log ("In my func2");
};

models.Picture.prototype.relativeSort = function(viewer_location) {
console.log("Rel Sort");

var sortedPics = [];
var relsortedPics = [];

 // Finds all the pictures
 async.series([myfunc1(), myfunc2()],
 function(err, results){
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
 console.log("call back func");
    return a+b;
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `callback` argument, for example:

```
var myfunc1 = function(callback) {
    var a = 1;
    console.log ("In my func1");
    callback(null, 'test');
};
```

The first argument of `callback` is an error, and the second the result you want to pass to the final handler.

**EDIT**

I've missed the other mistake. This line:

```
async.series([myfunc1(), myfunc2()],
```

should be

```
async.series([myfunc1, myfunc2],
```

You are not supposed to **call** functions. You are telling `async`: "Hey, take these functions and do something (asynchronous) with them!".

Comment: It does not work...On the line callback (null, 'test') it has an error 500 TypeError: undefined is not a function